# Can't extract text from website using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to retrieve text from a website (indeed) but I'm unable to retrieve it.

This is how the HTML essentially looks like:

```
<div id="jobDescriptionText" class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText">
 <p>Text</p>
 <ul>
  <li>Text</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The actual html has more `<p>` and `<ul>` tags. I've tried to use `.getText()`, `.text` and `.getAttribute()` with `innerText` and `innerHtml` but nothing seems to be working. I've also tried to call it by it's x path, id, css selector and class but that doesn't work too.

The website has different classes and id' at different times so I've tried to account for it by adding different id's and classes' based on the HTML in a try except block. I only run into trouble with getting the text when the above html line pops up. This is a part of the code:

```
try:
 for i in range(14):
 postings=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result') #collects all job listings
except:
 print('Error in retrieving postings')

counts=0 
rate=[]

for job in postings: #sorts through each listing

 try:
  result_html = job.get_attribute('innerHTML')
  soup = BeautifulSoup(result_html, 'html.parser')

 except:
  print('Error in retreiving job from postings')

 sleep(randint(10,15))

 while True:

  try: #retreiving text
   try: 
    job.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(7)
    description0=(driver.find_element_by_id('vjs-content').text)
    counts=counts+1
    break
  except Exception as e:
    job.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(7)
    description0=(driver.find_element_by_id('vjs-desc').text)
    counts=counts+1
    break
  except Exception as e:
    job.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(7)
    description0=(driver.find_element_by_id('jobDescriptionText').text)
    counts=counts+1
    break
  except Exception as e:
    job.click()
    driver.implicitly_wait(7)
    description0=(driver.find_element_by_class('jobsearch-jobDescriptionText').text)
    counts=counts+1
    break
 except:
   print("Error in retreiving description for listing")
   break
```

Comment: In python it's `get_attribute()` or `text`, but it doesn't matter as there is no text in the html you provided. What value are you trying to get?

Comment: What url are you using?

Comment: Just edited the post to indicate where the text in the html will be.                                                     
I'm using ae.indeed.com

Comment: What is the output of this code ? Is there any error ?

Comment: All I get is the print statement I put in the except: "Error in retreiving description for listing"

Comment: Don't mask the exception. It's also try to tell with this indentation, but the `try except` structure doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: The ID for the div tag varies in each page and I wanted it go through different IDs to get the text. If I don’t use try except it breaks down when it hits a different ID.